# The Shell Script code.Is It working Fine

Tags: php, encryption, whatsapp

The shell script code present [here](http://www.digitalinternals.com/279/20140330/decrypt-whatsapp-crypt5-database-messages/) is it working fine.
I have used it but its decryption is partial.
I opened the decrypted file in "**SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1**"
It creates table only.It is not inserting data.

I have used it in php by calling

```
shell_exec("wacrypt5.sh abc@gmail.com msgstore.db.crypt5 > msgstore.db");
```

Comment: just **sigh**, why do you even bother?

Comment: I want to decryt whats app database. With this script I am able to do. Please help me out.

Comment: Please try at least to format your question and make sure it is *self contained*.